# Restrict users with specific roles to login in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created login and signup form by wp-members plugin in wordpress. This form is only for certain role for e.g recruiters. When someone login with credentials, his role should be checked whether he is recruiter or not and then only he should be allowed to login otherwise error message should be displayed.
      I am facing difficulty to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login is not about authorization, but authentication. You should use a plugin like adminimize (https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) and restrict functionalities by role.